# PostgreSql procedure structure

Tags: postgresql, procedure

I have a syntax error on a procedure (PostgreSQL) and I can't find the mistake. I need a procedure with the variable declaration, a for loop, and a transaction.

Here is a sample of the structure I'm using.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE repor_dados()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
   utilizador int;
   data_acesso date;
   r record;
BEGIN
    BEGIN -- begin transaction
    
        select 2 ,4 into data_acesso,utilizador;

        IF EXISTS(select 2) then -- condition
        BEGIN 
        -- for each select result
            FOR r IN SELECT 1,2,3
            LOOP
                -- do something
                
                IF r = 1 THEN
                    SELECT 3;
                ELSE
                    SELECT 4;
                END IF;
                
            END LOOP;
        END;
    COMMIT; -- commit transaction
END
$$
```

I am working with PostgreSQL 13.2.
The error is:

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input LINE 30: $$

Comment: This: `BEGIN -- begin transaction` is the problem, it is not needed. See [Transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html).  The second `BEGIN/END;` in the `IF` is superfluous.

Comment: [without error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d7d5ec148bebf1f1a7c88121817dc0f1)

Comment: I'm sorry but when I execute the procedure I get the error: ERROR:  unsupported transaction command in PL/pgSQL